# How to enable free tagging?

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, entities

I'm using Drupal 8 and I would like to allow free tagging my website. There should be a field on the node edit page for tags that the user can add new or existing tag(s) to the page.

What field should I use and how must I configure it?

Comment: Please be aware that we do not provide tutorials or step-by-step instructions for achieving functionality from a description, screenshot or other website, as explained in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead explain your attempt(s), and be as complete as possible. What have you tried, what did you expect, what actually happened? If you have any code to include in the question, please add it. The more complete you are, the better we can formulate an answer.

Comment: Even i dont know how free tagging works ,how could i explain?

Comment: I just want to take a rough idea ,or about any related module

Comment: Dnt put this question on hold ,it may be helpfull for others too,if question is not clear how people are giving working solution?.

Comment: the problem is about the cloud part. It makes no sense. I have changed the question so it is clearer what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what a *free tagging cloud* is, but I can help you with setting up a free tagging field.

On your entity (content type), add an **entity reference field** that references **taxonomy terms**. Optionally you can limit to a specific vocabulary. Also select the checkbox to create new items if they do not yet exist.

Then on the manage form display tab of the content type, make sure that you select the **Autocomplete (Tags style)** as the Widget for your created field. This should give you a free tagging text field.

(You can use the Article content type of a clean Drupal site as example)